# How to make devilspie match Spotify windows?

Tags: gnome3, devilspie

I would like to create a `devilspie` (the one with Lisp-like syntax, however, a solution for `devilspie2` would be just as good) rule that matches windows of the Spotify music streaming app. Specifically, I would like to set its `_GTK_THEME_VARIANT` property to `dark` so that the color of its title bar matches the rest of its theme.

Currently, I am using

```
 (is (window_class) "Spotify")
```

as condition, which seems to work fine if I start devilspie when Spotify already has its window open. However, if I start Spotify when devispie is already running, my rule does not match. It seems Spotify only sets its `window_class` after its window was already created, therefore the match fails on the creation event. The same thing happens if I use `(application_name)` instead of `(window_class)`. I can match other windows upon their creation with `(window_class)` just fine.

*Is there any way to make a rule that can match Spotify windows when the app starts up?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently noticed that

```
(is (application_name) "Untitled window")
```

matches Spotify as it starts. I did not notice this query matching other windows. Remarkably, it does not even match other Electron apps such as the Slack desktop client.

Devilspie running on the console prints the `window_name`, `application_name` and `window_class` of windows as they are detected, thus information about a window can be obtained as it opens.

It seems Spotify sets its `application_name` and `windows_class` to `Spotify` later, hence the values obtained by using `xprop` on the already opened window do not match the values detected by devilspie right as the window is opened.